# Database client abstractions

Tags: node.js, database, design-patterns, architecture, abstraction

I have read many times that it is a good idea to write a layer of abstraction over any database clients, so that you can change the DB layer without affecting any other parts of the code.

In my project I use both BigQuery and Firebase quite heavily - but the client libs are so simple to use, I am not sure what I can add as a layer of abstraction, for example:

```
  await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
```

I could wrap this in a function, which would include a little error handling.

The other option is that I make this new client more coupled to my domain, and expose methods which would save specific datasets rather than just take a `rows` object - this seems like it would be detrimental.

How does one abstract database in nodejs applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important part is to **make your domain not depend on the implementation details**. The database is an implementation detail.

So it's not much about wrapping that in a function to give it another name. The point is to make your domain not depend on that.

### How do you do that?

By defining an interface (this is your abstraction) that says "I need to store/get the data, whatever DB is behind". Then, you inject the BigQuery implementation of that interface in prod… and it's easy to inject an in-memory implementation in tests or even in dev mode.

Now, in JavaScript, there is no explicit interface. But the idea of the abstraction still exist. It's just implicit. The interface will be the things you actually use (duck typing).

### Using your concrete example

Let's say you had:

```
async function doSomething() {
  // Some other domain stuff…

  await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
}
```

This wouldn't help much:

```
function insertInDb(rows) {
  return bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
}


async function doSomething() {
  // Some other domain stuff…

  await insertInDb(rows);
}
```

However, this would help:

```
function insertInDb(rows) {
  return bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
}


async function doSomething(insertInDb) {
  // Some other domain stuff…

  await insertInDb(rows);
}
```

The difference is subtle, but the actual `insertInDb` function is injected at runtime, which inverts the dependency.

### Going further: the Repository abstraction over databases

Now, this concept is usually named a Repository.

If you spend some time expressing the domain concepts better, you might have final code that looks like:

```
class ScoreRepositoryBigQuery {
  save(newScore) {
    // Some logic to convert `newScore` into BigQuery compatible `rows`…

    return this.bigquery
      .dataset(this.datasetId)
      .table(this.tableId)
      .insert(rows);
  }
}


async function answerQuestion(scoreRepository) {
  // Some other domain stuff…

  await scoreRepository.save(newScore);
}
```

It would be easy to create a new `ScoreRepository` using a different storing mechanism (e.g. MongoDB, a third-party service, in-memory implementation, etc.).

You would just need to implement the implicit interface (e.g. it should have an async `save()` method that takes a `newScore` and store it).

No need to touch the rest of the code, since it doesn't care the actual implementation.

So *this* would be a useful layer of abstraction.

Comment: Thank you @nicoespeon! In your first example, you "invert the dependency" but why is this useful? I would import the function to store into the file, or have to pass it as an arg to the function - I am unsure of the benefits.

Comment: Hey @dendog! 

Thanks for asking, I realized I didn't explained *why* it's useful. By passing it as an arg to the function, you can decide to pass a different one. When would you pass a different one? If you want to change where the data comes from. 

E.g. you want to provide an in-memory implementation that doesn't connect to firebase in dev mode… or in tests! Separate responsibilities, let the caller decide where the data should be stored. Keep the logic agnostic of that decision. 

This you can only achieve by "inverting the dependency".

Comment: Thank you again @nicoespeon - I think it is starting to come together, the repository pattern seems nice, good example I think here https://github.com/ErickWendel/generic-repository-nodejs-typescript-article